# EnumerateChildNodesWithName access method

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

I want to find some nodes by name and then call a function called update on that node.

have the following code:

```
encounter.enumerateChildNodesWithName(enemy)
{            
    node, stop in
    node.update()              
}
```

I cannot call the method update() my enemy class looks like this

```
class EnemyPrototype: SKSpriteNode, EnemySprite
{
  func update(){}
}
```

Why does it not work?

I guess that node is referencing the SKSpriteNode class but not the EnemyPrototype class.

Or am I just using EnumerateChildNodesWithName incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the node is SKNode. You have to downcast it to EnemyPrototype like this:

```
encounter.enumerateChildNodesWithName("enemy"){ node , stop in

    if let enemy = node as? EnemyPrototype {

         enemy.update()
    }          
}
```

I assume that downcast can fail (for example if you have other nodes of different types added to encounter node) so I use conditional downcast `as?` operator rather than `as!` version (forced downcast) of this operator.